# Missing dll's Qt 5.12 release build

Tags: windows-7, windows, dll, dependencies, qt

- Windows 7 machine
- QtCreator 4.8.0
- Qt 5.12.0
- MSVC2015 64-bit
- Compiler MSVC C++ 14.0 (x86_amd64)

I am trying to create a very simple program which I would like to share with my colleagues. They do not have Qt installed and need to have an executable. I was unsuccessful as the exe had many dependencies which I was unable to find.

To debug the issue I started from scratch with a Qt Widgets Application that does *nothing* (i.e. just the header file, main.cpp and mainWindow.cpp). When I run the program in QtCreator it builds successfully and exits with code 0. An executable is created and by running windeployqt all the required Qt dll's are copied to the directory. However, the windows dll's are missing. Using the dependency walker I can see that a whole list of windows dll's are missing. I do not understand why so many dll's are required for a program that does nothing. I am able to find some of the dll's in the x64\ilc\lib\MSCRT\ directory, but most of the required API-MS-WIN-CORE-xxx-x-x-x.dll's are not available. I have read posts of similar issues but could not relate the proposed solutions to my situation. Any advice is appreciated, it is a work laptop, hence re-installing windows is not an option.[DependencyWalker screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCjIw.png).

**edited** When running the Qt executable.... (links to screen shots below)
[First Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRjet.png)

[Second Error message, after including VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGp0G.png)

[Output from dependency tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qovgq.jpg)

Comment: Dependency Walker will complain about the `API-MS-*` files even if you have them on the system.  "I do not understand why so many dll's are required for a program that does nothing." - Your program does not actually require those files.

Comment: Unfortunately the Qt executable also requests these dll's. I have edited the post above and included screen shots to show the 1st error message. Then I copied the VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll to the directory and received the 2nd error message. At this point I am unable to proceed as the requested dll is not present on my system.

Answer (score 1):

These DLLs have in their time also caused me some head scratching,
so I take the opportunity to expose this mystery once and for all.

The `API-MS-*` DLLs are not really missing - the problem is with the dependency walker.
These fake DLLs were added in Windows Vista that dates from 2007, while the
dependency walker dates from 2006 and was never updated since.

[Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/articles/windows_7_kernel_architecture_changes.html)
has analyzed these DLLs and has shown that they are very small and basically
contain no useful code.
When Windows loads them, their import entries are replaced by calls to real functions
in the Windows kernel.

The article
[On API-MS-WIN-XXXXX.DLL, and Other Dependency Walker Glitches](https://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/)
calls them by the name of "Api Sets" and gives this historical perspective:

> Sometime in the Vista dev cycle an effort referred to as [MinWin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin) began:
>   essentially, smart people started moving functionality around in hope
>   of simplifying the OS architecture. To protect the myriad components
>   from breaking during a change, the ultimate solution was called in: an
>   extra layer of indirection. This level is exactly Api Sets.
>
> For example, the API set `api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1.dll` is an
>   ‘atom’ of functionality encompassing the 5 APIs `FlsAlloc`, `FlsFree`,
>   `FlsGetValue`, `FlsSetValue` and `IsThreadAFiber` (it is an untypically
>   small such ‘atom’). All applications that consume fiber functionality
>   declare dependency on this API set, and thereby become insensitive to
>   the exact location of implementation (that might change between OS
>   releases). During load time, the OS searches somewhere and
>   automatically routes the calls from `api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1.dll`
>   to wherever they happen to be implemented in this OS version.
>
> The actual per-OS-version redirection data lies in a special file called `ApiSetSchema.dll`. It's technically a DLL (conforms to the PE spec), but not an executable one – the redirection data lies in a specialized section called `.apiset`, mentioned at the `apiset.h` macros. [Sebastien Renaud](https://blog.quarkslab.com/runtime-dll-name-resolution-apisetschema-part-i.html) did some spectacular reversing work and described the layout of the redirection data it contains.

A more modern version of the dependency walker, also free, can be found in
[Github Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies),
and does a better job of unmasking these DLLs:

[image]

Comment: Your input does clear things up quite a bit, especially w.r.t. dependency walker (I am very new to this area). However, the executable (the one that does nothing!) also requests these dll's. I have only gone as far as the 2nd error, am unable to process as this dll does not exist on my system (afaik). Original post edited and screen shots added above.

Comment: Do you think this might be a Qt specific issue and perhaps I should post this question on a Qt specific forum?

Comment: No, there is no problem here, except that of using an ancient program such as the dependency walker. Use the newer Dependencies product above and you will have no problem, or just ignore these messages if you prefer to continue with the old dependency walker. The old dependency walker will give these spurious warnings on almost any Windows program in the world.

Comment: Understood. I am no longer looking at dependency walker, it is just that the executable itself requests these files when I try to run it. *Update* Just shared the program source files with a colleague and asked him to create an executable. It worked fine, executable created, no additional windows dll's were required. He is running windows 10 and an earleir version of Qt. I will switch to an earlier version and have another go.

Comment: Which DLLs were missing? Use Github Dependencies for a real list of missing DLLs.

Comment: Just by reading the error messages when trying to execute the executable generated. The 1st request is for vcruntime140_app.dll, once that is added, it requests api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll. The api-ms-.... is not even on my system. I think it is an issue with windows 7. I have now tried it with an earlier version of Qt (5.8) and have received the same error message. My colleague with Q7 5.8 and windows 10 did not experience any issues running the executable that was built on his system (same source code). I suspect this is a Qt <-> Windows7 build issue.

Comment: I will clone the dependency tool that is on github and check it once more.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the output from the dependency tool. The dependency requirements for the windows dll's seem sensible! One point that is a strange is that the dependency tool reports the checksum on the Qt dll's are incorrect. I will look to see if anyone else has experienced this issue! (Progress!!)

Comment: You are missing the [Visual C++ 2017 runtime](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), section "Other Tools and Frameworks". I would ignore such warning messages once everything works.

Comment: Hi, I have visual C++ 2017 and 2015 installed. Even if I compile the Qt project with 2015, it requests these dll's for the exe to run. I did some more searching and someone on [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1248628/Qt-on-windows-problem) suggests that it is an issue with windows 7. I creating the executable on my colleagues laptop (same version of Qt, and Visual C++ 2015, but Windows10). It worked perfectly. Some windows dll's were required but not they were different to the ones requested on my system and not as many. Will get my system upgraded to 10 and try again.

Comment: The Qt project might be set to use the wrong runtime.